# Relations reset on JPA OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

Code snippet for brevity under `hibernate-entitymanager 5.2.8.Final` below,

```
@Entity public class A {
    @Id@GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();
    public void add(B b) { this.b.add(b); }
}

@Entity public class B {
    @Id@GeneratedValue private Long id;
}

public class Service {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;
    private EntityTransaction tx;

    public Service() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        tx = em.getTransaction();
    }

    public void create(Object obj) {
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(obj);
        tx.commit();
    }

    public void update(A a, B b) {
        tx.begin();
        a.add(b);
        tx.commit();
    }
}

public class ServiceTest {
    @Test public void test() {
        Service s = new Service();
        A a = new A();
        s.create(a);
        B b1 = new B();
        s.update(a, b1);
        B b2 = new B();
        s.update(a, b2); // reset relation before adding new ?
    }
}
```

Why did the last update have to reset the existing relation `a_b1` before adding the new relation `a_b2` below ? Is it just implementation specific issue?

```
insert into A (id) values (1);
insert into B (id) values (2);
insert into A_B (A_id, b_id) values (1, 2);
insert into B (id) values (3);
delete from A_B where A_id=1;
insert into A_B (A_id, b_id) values (1, 2);
insert into A_B (A_id, b_id) values (1, 3);
```

**@EDIT**

It's not reproducible under `eclipselink 2.6.4`, so could be just an implementation issue.